# Replacing apostrophes in a Java string with a " \' "

Tags: java, weka

I am currently working on a project that involves using Weka to classify headlines based on their crime type. Since Weka uses .arff files, any headline with an apostrophe in it must be escaped.

```
List<String> headlines = demoPipe.getHeadlines();
    for (int i = 0; i < headlines.size(); i++) {

        if(headlines.get(i).contains("'"))
            headlines.get(i).replace("'", "\\'");

        System.out.println(headlines.get(i));

        //System.out.printf("'%s'%n", headline);
    }
```

The if statement is where I'm trying to escape the apostrophes, however when I print out the headlines, any headlines with apostrophes remain unchanged. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This will add backslashes forever if you run it more than once. You may need a more robust way.

Comment: strings are immutable, `headlines.get(i).replace("'", "\\'");` ignores the result.

Comment: There is also this type of apostrophe: ’

Answer (score 3):

strings are immutable, meaning any modification to a string yields a new string with the new modifications and leaves the previous string unchanged.

```
headlines.get(i).replace("'", "\\'");
```

The above `replace` operation is returning a new string object with the new modifications but you're ignoring it.

So, to overcome the problem you'll need to utilise the `set` method of the `List<T>` and assign back the new string.

```
headlines.set(i,headlines.get(i).replace("'", "\\'"));
```

Further, you can simplify the replacing logic with the `replaceAll` method as of JDK-8:

```
headlines.replaceAll(s -> s.contains("'") ? s.replace("'", "\\'") : s);
```

if for whatever reason, you don't want to modify the source list then you can collect the results to a new list as follows:

```
List<String> result = 
       headlines.stream()
                .map(s -> s.contains("'") ? s.replace("'", "\\'") : s)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

or you can print directly to the console without constructing a new list:

```
headlines.stream()
         .map(s -> s.contains("'") ? s.replace("'", "\\'") : s)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it won't replace like you are doing. Few days ago same problem I was facing. You have to assign it to make it useful.

```
List<String> headlines = demoPipe.getHeadlines();
    for (int i = 0; i < headlines.size(); i++) {

        if(headlines.get(i).contains("'"))
            headlines.set(i,headlines.get(i).replace("'", "\'"));

        System.out.println(headlines.get(i));

        //System.out.printf("'%s'%n", headline);
    }
```

Try like this it will work for you.

Comment: Mixing `List` and *array* logic there.

Comment: I have given you the solution idea... You just need to set the value from after replacing..

Comment: I don't need anything, but you are showing code that won't compile. It is also badly formatted. You should *edit* the answer and fix it.

Comment: is it fine now ?